# F# GetDigitValue value or construct not valid

Tags: f#

I am new to F# and would like to have an advice.

I would like to use the GetDigitValue function.

```
open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Globalization

    let getSubscript ichar = 
        match ichar with 
        |1 -> GetDigitValue(843)
        | _ -> GetDigitVale(852)
```

I have the following error: The value or constructor 'getDigitValue" is not defined.

Comment: What is the error that you keep having? Also what exactly do you want your code to do? What do you think the result of `GetDigitValue(843)` should be?

Comment: I would like to get the superscript of numbers. CharUnicodeInfo.GetDigitValue(182) = superscript of 1. (the 843 is not corrected, sorry)

Comment: I am assuming the second line in the pattern match should be GetDigitValue not GetDigitVale. Please give us your _exact_ code.

Answer (score 6):

Without further information I can't really tell what you are trying to do.

GetDigitValue is a static method of the [CharUnicodeInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/3e7h1yeb%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

It is used like this:

```
let testString = "1234567890"
let digitValue = CharUnicodeInfo.GetDigitValue(testString, 3)
```

This returns the digit value for the 3rd character in the string.  It also works with a single character too.

```
let test = '5'
let digitvalue =  CharUnicodeInfo.GetDigitValue(test)
```

**Update:**
To get the superscript of a string I think the Numeric value will return this:

```
let superscriptTwo ="U+00B2"
let numericvalue = CharUnicodeInfo.GetNumericValue(superscriptTwo)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I would like to get the superscript of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get the superscript of numbers.

Then I think you want this function that gives a unicode character that is the superscript of the given digit:

```
let superscriptOf n =
  if 0<=n && n<10 then "⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹".[n] else
    invalidArg "n" "Not a single digit number"
```

Note that F# supports unicode in F# code. You can even use unicode variable names like λ in F# code!